# Output season name from entry date

Tags: templating

I'd like to get an output of **Spring 2015** from a post entry that was written in March. Here is a JavaScript solution

http://jsfiddle.net/RtC58/3/

But I'm hoping I can do something in the template instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{% switch entry.postDate|date('M') %}

    {% case 'Dec' or 'Jan' or 'Feb' %}
        {% set season = 'Winter' %}

    {% case 'Mar' or 'Apr' or 'May' %}
        {% set season = 'Spring' %}

    {% case 'Jun' or 'Jul' or 'Aug' %}
        {% set season = 'Summer' %}

    {% case 'Sep' or 'Oct' or 'Nov' %}
        {% set season = 'Fall' %}

{% endswitch %}

<p>{{ season }} {{ entry.postDate|date('Y') }}</p>
```

Comment: That is way simpler than what I would have tried. Thanks!

Comment: Wow. Didn't actually know you could have an `or` statement inside a `{% case %}` tag. +1, Lindsey!

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff: That's a brand new feature as of Craft 2.6!